# Why arrow key navigation doesn't work (or focus) in Dropdown in React Select when the option is modified?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have been working with React Select and I am just wondering why the arrow key navigation doesn't work when I try to modify option in the drop-down.

My implementation goes below.

```
<Select
    styles={_customStyles}
    isClearable={false}
    isSearchable={true}
    options={sitesOptions}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={selectedOption}
    menuIsOpen={true}
/>
```

and the **_customStyles** goes below,

```
const _customStyles = {
        control: (base, state) => ({
            ...base,
            boxShadow: 'none',
            minWidth: '242px',
            zIndex: 9999,
            border: '1px solid lightgray', // default border color
            '&:hover': { borderColor: 'gray' } // border style on hover
        }),
        option: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#d46514' : 'transparent',
            ':focus, :hover, :active, :visited': {
                backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#d46514' : '#5a61691a'
            }
        })
    };
```

If I remove the options object from _customStyles, I can able to navigate through the list in the drop-down. In another way, I can navigate but it was transparent. I don't know the currently selected item but when I hit 'Enter' the option gets selected.

Why the backgroundColor is not applying to the element? It was transparent. When I remove option, default colours would be applied and it's working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `&:focus, &:hover...`? if yes, did you inspect the element while it works, what classes are applied to the element - is it the `:focus` pseudoclass or some `.customFocus` class?

Comment: @Aprillion Yeah, I have tried adding &:focus, &:hover but still it's not working. Secondly, the styles are been applied to the element when I try to force element state in Inspector window. But when I try to navigate using arrow keys, it's not working.

Comment: ok, that meas that the React Select does NOT apply the `:focus` pseudoclass, but some other class using JS events. what class is applied when you try it without your `option` == when it actually works?

Comment: :active pseudo-class is been applied when we don't modify option. But I tried with active too.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't style the isFocused state then focused options will get the same styling as non-selected ones. Try something like this instead:

```
backgroundColor: state.isFocused || state.isSelected ? '#d46514' : 'transparent'
```

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, I found the other way and hope it might help others.

I removed the pseudo-class declarations from the **_customStyles** and added them using CSS. I made use of **classNamePrefix** prop from react-select and added the custom class **react-select** as a prefix to my react-select elements.

```
<Select
    styles={_customStyles}
    isClearable={false}
    isSearchable={true}
    options={sitesOptions}
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={selectedOption}
    menuIsOpen={true}
    classNamePrefix="react-select"
/>
```

Check the **classNamePrefix**. And now in CSS,

```
.react-select__option--is-focused:not(.react-select__option--is-selected) {
    background-color: rgba(90, 97, 105, 0.10196078431372549);
}
```

And _customStyles again for your reference.

```
const _customStyles = {
        control: (base, state) => ({
            ...base,
            boxShadow: 'none',
            minWidth: '242px',
            zIndex: 9999,
            border: '1px solid lightgray', // default border color
            '&:hover': { borderColor: 'gray' } // border style on hover
        }),
        option: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#d46514' : '#fff'
        })
    };
```

Now, I can able to navigate using arrow keys with the colours I required.

> **Note:** React Select encourage you to use the new Styles API. Check this link [React Select](https://react-select.com/styles) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

This worked well for me to have three different colors. For example blue for selected, light blue for focused, and transparent for the rest.

```js
 option: (provided, { isSelected, isFocused }) => ({
    ...provided,

    backgroundColor:
      (isSelected && blue) ||
      (isFocused && lightBlue) ||
      'transparent',

    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: lightBlue,
      color: isSelected ? blue : darkGrey,
    },
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tab to a react-select it adds an `aria-live="polite"` span that provides use instructions to assistive devices. Apparently they rely on this instead of visual cues.

```
<span aria-live="polite" class="css-1laao21-a11yText">
    <p id="aria-selection-event">&nbsp;option Relevant, selected.</p>
    <p id="aria-context">&nbsp; option Relevant focused, 1 of 3. 3 results
available. Use Up and Down to choose options, press Enter to select the 
currently focused option, press Escape to exit the menu, press Tab to 
select the option and exit the menu.</p>
</span>
```

It also adds menu items that have `tabindex="-1"` which disables tab navigation to those elements since they are using arrows to navigate and Tab to select.

```
<div class=" css-12evx9e-menu">
    <div class=" css-4ljt47-MenuList">
        <div class=" css-1p3yiqo-option" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1">Relevant</div>
        <div class=" css-14xmj0o-option" id="react-select-2-option-1" tabindex="-1">Newest</div>
        <div class=" css-1p3yiqo-option" id="react-select-2-option-2" tabindex="-1">Oldest</div>
    </div>
</div>
```